# Running loop on groups of data frame in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I need to code a loop that will run `t-tests` on small groups of a data frame. I think they recommended using a `for loop`.
There are 271 rows in the data frame. The first 260 rows need to be split into 13 groups of 20, and a `t-test` must be run on each of the 13 groups.

This is the code I used to run a `t-test` on the entire data frame:

```
t.test(a, c, alternative =c("two.sided"), mu=0, paired=TRUE, var.equal=TRUE, conf.level=0.95)
```

I'm a coding noob, please help! D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all, I don't see a data.frame here. `a` and `c` seem to be vectors. I assume that these both vectors are of length 271 and you want to ignore the last 11 items. So you can throw away these items first:

```
a2 <- a[1:260]
c2 <- c[1:260]
```

Now you can create a vector of length 260 determining the indices of the subsets. (There are many ways to do this, but I think this way is easy to understand.)

```
indices <- as.numeric(cut(1:260, 20))
indices  #just to show the output
```

You probably have to store the output in a list. The following code is again not the most efficient, but easy to understand.

```
result <- list()
for (i in 1:20){
  result[[i]] <- t.test(a2[which(indices == i)], c2[which(indices == i)],
                        alternative = c("two.sided"),
                        mu = 0, paired = TRUE, var.equal = TRUE,
                        conf.level = 0.95)
}
result[[1]] #gives the results of the first t-test (items 1 to 20)
result[[2]] # ...
```

As alternative to the `for`-loop you could also use `lapply` which usually is more effective and a bit shorter (but that doesn't matter for 260 data points):

```
result2 <- lapply(1:20, function(i) t.test(a2[which(indices == i)],
                                           c2[which(indices == i)],
                                           alternative = c("two.sided"),
                                           mu = 0, paired = TRUE, var.equal = TRUE,
                                           conf.level = 0.95))
result[[1]] # ...
```

I hope that answers you're question.

Comment: Hey sorry, I figured the data frame was too large and messy. A and c represent columns in the data frame

Thank you so much for your help!